# Uploading live streaming video from iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, http-live-streaming

How to live stream videos from iPhone to server like Ustream or Qik? I know there's something called Http Live Streaming from Apple, but most resources I found only talks about streaming videos from server to iPhone.any help pls?
we have to implement  HTTP Live streaming concepts? is there any API to upload to server?