# Can iOS device use http live streaming to sent audio/video back to server?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

So http live streaming let you send live video to iOS devices but how do iOS devices send live audio/video back to server ? Can they use http live stream as well ? For example for video conference app like webex or facetime , how do iOS devices send audio/video back to server ?

Of course there are iOS API to let you make phone-call app, but I would like what happens behind the scene, especially can HLS be used to send streaming back to server ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062266/uploading-live-streaming-video-from-iphone/5601041

Answer (score 0):

HLS doesn't send data back to a server. It makes data available for download via HTTP. To send data to a server, you can push it back in basically any way you want, even with HTTP via a POST. Sending it to the server isn't that hard, really.

Harder is capturing the audio+video, but that's not insurmountable. You can see the [AVCam sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) to get started.

Comment: "HLS doesn't send data back to a server. It makes data available for download via HTTP." No, HLS is an application-layer TCP/IP protocol, so it sends data to whoever it pleases...