# Can I stream a video FROM my iPhone or iPad TO a server?

Tags: iphone, ios4, video-streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I want to live stream a video FROM iPhone to a remote server. Is that possible? If yes, how to do it? Please guide. I searched a lot but was not able to find a clear answer. The AVFoundation framework helps to record the video. But it can be streamed only when saved. I want to do a LIVE streaming.

Comment: technically this is possible (FaceTime does something like that)... please show some code... what have you tried ?

Comment: i used the [link](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/articles/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera) tutorial. It was helpful to get the still frames from the video. But after reading few more pages, i came across ffmpeg encoding. Since then i am still reading about it n haven't tried much.

Comment: Did you implemented this?If It so,Please post it as Answer

Comment: Just refer to the following threads. First one helps you to capture the frames in realtime and the second one guides how to upload http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062266/uploading-live-streaming-video-from-iphone/5601041#5601041 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719538/realtime-audio-video-streaming-from-iphone-to-another-device-browser-or-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible
You can use a third party library called OPEN TOK
have not used it before 
but heard it quite useful maybe u should check it out see if it helps
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it but you will need a streaming server (wowza,red5,fms).

After that, you just need to know how to get an h264 stream from the camera of your phone and publish it to your server. It's possible through RTP/RTSP or through RTMP.

To have some exemple, Livu code was released as an LGPL project 2 years ago. Code is available here : https://github.com/otmakie/LivuLib

You can also look at this topic : [Uploading live streaming video from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062266/uploading-live-streaming-video-from-iphone/5601041#5601041)