# Best Route to Stream Music from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio-streaming

I am looking for an efficient way to stream music from iPhone to iPhone. These iPhones would be nearby each other so one of my options was to use their Bluetooth features.

This forum, http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1464189.html, explained how to stream from iPhone to a Ubuntu computer but didn't explain how to capture.

My first thought was to capture the raw bytes being played from an iPhones speaker. I saw how to do it with a camera stream, here [Uploading live streaming video from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062266/uploading-live-streaming-video-from-iphone/5601041#5601041),  but I don't believe it's the same methods for an avaudioplayer.

Can anyone extend over the information I've collected or suggest a different feasible option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer should be updated, because with IOS7 you can use [MultiPeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) to send data to nearby peers over bluetooth/direct wifi

And the MCSession protocol implements
startStreamWithName:toPeer:error: to create a connected byte stream (NSOutputStream) that you can use to send data to the specified peer.

Answer (score 2):

[Game Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW17) provides easy peer-to-peer connectivity:

> **Peer-to-peer connectivity** allows your game to create an ad hoc
>   Bluetooth or wireless network between multiple iPhones in the same
>   local area. Although designed with games in mind, this network is
>   useful for any type of data exchange among users of your app. For
>   example, an app could use peer-to-peer connectivity to share
>   electronic business cards or other data. This functionality is only
>   available on iOS. You can also get the same functionality using Game
>   Center.

Comment: would this be a stream or a download

Comment: @kdogisthebest, I think that's a question for you. It's your choice. However you want to implement it.

Comment: I think I understand. So when I am using the GameKit I can send the bytes block by block or send the whole file?

Comment: @kdogisthebest, Correct. You send the data in the raw as `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

To capture and play the streamed audio you can use [Audio File Stream Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162)

To stream the audio data to another Iphone, you want to take a look at the new Multipeer Connectivity framework in ios7. It allows you to stream data to nearby peers through a multipeer connectivity session.

Comment: Anything in ios5 and later?